# How do I realize One Input One Output in Nodejs with the module child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I try to make R and nodejs communicate with each other, but I run into some problems. I will explain it more with this chunk of code

```
var cp = require('child_process')
var spawn = cp.spawn

var r = spawn("rterm",["--ess" ,"--slave"])

r.stdout.on('data',function(data){
     console.log(data.toString())
    })
```

I send a command to the child process, the child process then generates a lot of output(within a reasonable length), the output is automatically read back by Nodejs because of 'data' listener.

But for the child process, the output is one chunk, then when read back by Nodejs, it becomes two or more chunks SOMETIMES. And that is not what I wanted.

How do I fix that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn a [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout), stdout is a [Readable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). When you attach a '[data](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data)' event, the stream goes into 'flowing mode', meaning that it will return the data as soon as it is available. When you have a lot of data, it will return your data one chunk at a time.

There's a couple of ways to fix that :

You could buffer all the chunks, and output them when the '[end](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end)' event is fired, like below :

```
var output="";
r.stdout.on('data',function(data){
  output+=data
}).on('end',function(){
  console.log(output);
});
```

Or, you can remove the data event listener altogether and call [stdout.read()](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size).

stdout.read() will read all the content of the stream at any moment, so you must call it when your process won't output anything anymore.

Comment: I have tried the code, that is not what I wanted neither. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I send ONE command to R, I get this command's output, let's say that this output is read back in two chunks by Nodejs because of the data listener. What can I do so that when nodejs read back, it is ONE chunk, I write code to process this chuck of output. Then I send another command, I get another chunk, I do the same. In your way, output is buffered into one, then I have to write extra code to separate outputs according to commands, this is not possible and practical.

Comment: If you know the size of the output, you can increase the buffer size of your stream, but if you send one command only, my code will output the full result of your command. Not sure what you want...